# Порядок изучения материала в книге "Android Программирование для профессионалов"

Tags: java, android, книги

Читаю книгу "Android Программирование для профессионалов", сейчас дошёл до 12 главы.

Вопрос к тем, кто уже читал эту книгу до меня:

В книге по несколько глав создаётся одно приложение, следовательно эти главы имеют сильную взаимную связь, что делает невозможным прохождение их в произвольном порядке.
Но насколько связаны между собой главы, в которых создаются разные приложения и можно ли изменить порядок прохождения материала?
Вопрос связан со следующим, когда я пройду 14 главу (БД SQLite), ближайшие несколько глав будут посвящены таким темам, как "Интенты при работе с камерой", "Стили и темы", "Графические объекты" и т.д. Я знаю, что это важные темы (и я к ним обязательно вернусь), однако, судя по тому, какие тестовые задания я получал на собеседованиях, материал первостепенной важности (то, что, как мне кажется нужно изучить в ближайшее время), начинается с 26 главы.
Итак вопрос, могу ли я вначале пройти материал, начинающийся с 26 главы и до 30-той (или до конца), а затем вернутся к предыдущим главам или это создаст непреодолимые препятствия в следствии необходимости глубоки знаний материала из прошлых глав?

Comment: Кроилово ведёт к попадалову. Не надо экономить время на прочтение пары глав, рискуя качеством усвоения информации, читайте последовательно.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev вот прям истина.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev мне кажется это ответ, заслуживающий ордена "Зеленой Галочки"

Comment: Единственное, что хочется добавить к ответу SergeyGornostaev - не обязательно реализовывать в коде всё сразу. Можно просто прочитать эти главы, а уже позже вернуться к реализации в приложении.